# What is the best way to string multiple UITouches to specific frames/UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, uitouch

**i apolog**ize i am pretty new to objective-c and Xcode and I know I'm probably going to get some shit for this but I've been stuck on this for quite some time using different methods and defining different functions for not getting the results i want. -(void)TouchesBegan:LeftArrow{

what is the best way to string multiple UITouches with functions and methods in your app? here is an example, i am trying to create my first app and I'm trying to string a UITouch "Left Arrow" with "hero movement" that i have defined in a method. here is where i am at

```
-(void)TouchesBegan:LeftArrow{



}
-(void)TouchesMoved:LeftArrow {
}

-(void)TouchesEnded:LeftArrow{
}

-(void)TouchesBegan:RightArrow{
}

-(void)TouchesMoved:RigthArrow{
}

-(void)TouchesEnded:RightArrow{
```

//here is the function i am trying to get the UITouch to perform

```
-(void)heroMovementTimerMethod {

heroMovementTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speedOfhero
target:self selector:@selector(heroMovement) userInfo:nil
repeats:YES];

-(void)heroMovement{

hero.center = CGPointMake(hero.center.x +.5, hero.center.y );
```

what code do i need to execute to string the UITouch "LeftArrow" in my storyboard to the UITouch. Am i miss naming my (Void)touchesbegan:LeftArrow; method? or how do i initiate the method i have declared of hero movement timer?

Comment: So for clarification, are there a left arrow and right arrow button on the screen, and you want to make it so that when someone presses the left arrow or right arrow, the heroMovementTimerMethod function is called, and I'm assuming with different parameters so that the hero moves either left or right?

Comment: @JYeh yes exactly! thank you for your future help i have looked all over online but cannot find an answer to my exact question.

Answer (score 0):

The touchesBegan/Moved/Ended functions are not necessary. Since you have left and right arrow buttons in your Storyboard, you can create IBAction functions that are executed when someone taps the left or right arrow button.

Control + Drag from a button into the View Controller code (you can open the Storyboard and View Controller code side by side if you Option + Click on a file which puts that file side by side with the one currently open):

[image]

Give the action a name, then click Connect:

[image]

Then in the function that's created, put the code that you want executed, for example:

```
- (IBAction)leftArrowTapped:(id)sender {
    [self heroMovementTimerMethod];
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! but i have one question, i see that the IBAction is for a button "tap", would this code support the character continuously moving across the screen if the button is held down? so the user doesn't keep having to tap the arrow?

Comment: Yup, just change the Event to Touch Down.

Comment: It worked thank you for your help! but how to i invalidate the timer method once i let go of the button. lol when i hold it down my character moves but when i release the button the character continues to slide across the screen

Comment: Add another IBAction for another event, such as Touch Up Inside, Touch Up Outside, or Touch Cancel. Experiment with it to see which one you want, or a combination of them. The timer can be invalidated with the .invalidate() function.

Comment: which method do i define the invalidation? the new IBAction? hero movement? or HeroMovementTimerMethod?

Comment: Yes, the new IBAction.

Comment: i used touch cancelled, and it didn't change anything, here is how i did it. where did i go wrong?-(IBAction)LeftArrowTapped:(id)sender; {
    
    [self heroMovementTimerMethodLeft];
    
}
-(IBAction)RightArrowTapped:(id)sender; {
    
    [self heroMovementTimerMethodRight];
    
    }
-(IBAction)TouchCancelledLeft:(id)sender; {
    
    [heroMovementTimerLeft invalidate];
}

-(IBAction)TouchCancelledRight:(id)sender; {
    
    [heroMovementTimerRight invalidate];

Comment: I think touch cancel might actually mean something other than what we think it is. Did you try touch up inside or touch up outside or both of them?

Comment: i originally used touch up inside and touch up outside does not work. the character still slides

Comment: i even tried touch did end on exit. nothing will invalidate the method :(

Comment: here is what i have, maybe I'm doing something wrong.                                   -(IBAction)LeftArrowTapped:(id)sender; {
  
    [self heroMovementTimerMethodLeft];   
}
-(IBAction)RightArrowTapped:(id)sender; {
    
    [self heroMovementTimerMethodRight];  
}
-(IBAction)TouchendedLeft:(id)sender; {
        
    [heroMovementTimerLeft invalidate];
}
-(IBAction)TouchendedRight:(id)sender; {
    [heroMovementTimerRight invalidate];